# Hyperledger fabric src folder installation dir on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Greetings hyperledger devs,

I am trying to install the prerequisites for fabric project. Most of the tools are working including curl, docker, docker-compose, npm, go.

I have installed the go in usr/local/go and set the goroot to that folder.

and my fabric project is in separate folder in my home directory.

Do i need to move the fabric src code within the go root folder as i am getting the following error while running

`make cryptogen`

> can't load package: package github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim: cannot find package "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim" in any of:
>       /usr/local/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim (from $GOROOT)
>       /usr/local/go/bin/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim (from $GOPATH)
>   find: ‘/usr/local/go/bin/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim’: No such file or directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fabric-samples source tree can be installed outside the `$GOROOT`. To do this, you specify the path to which you can install various golang projects with the `$GOPATH` variable. e.g.

```
export GOPATH=/home/someacct/go
mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger
git clone -b master https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples.git
cd fabric-samples
...
```

The fabric-samples source tree can then be accessed from:

```
$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
```

Note that this is the more common way of handling things.

Answer (score 1):

To get Hyperledger Fabric sources you simply could run the following command which is by the way the proper way of installing go packages:

```
go get github.com/hyperledger/fabric
```

then you should be able to

```
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
```

and execute

```
make cryptogen
```

or use make file to just build whatever needed to your experiments. For example:

```
make peer orderer
```

will produce peer and orderer binaries respectively.

The binary artifacts will be available at `$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/build/bin` and of course to use them you have to make them available in your `$PATH`.

Of course you can just download platform specific binaries and use them right away w/o doing any local compilation.

Answer (score 0):

it worked. Have to put under

```
/usr/local/go
```

Steps to follow.

> created new folder inside /usr/local/go/src
>
> mkdir github.com
>
> mkdir hyperledger
>
> cd hyperledger/
>
> git clone -b master https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples.git
>
> curl Platform-specific Binaries from website.
>
> export PATH=/usr/local/go/src/hyperledger/bin:$PATH
>
> cd fabric-samples/first-network
>
> ./byfn.sh -m generate

and i can the beautiful console output. :)